# How to make my Angular and Spring boot microservices run on Apacheoffbiz

Tags: apache, spring-boot, jakarta-ee

I have developed back end micro services by using Spring boot and front end developed using Angular 2. My question is how make my project run on ApacgeOffbiz ?
Can any one guide me on this.

Thanks,
Sudheer